# Confusion over @2x and Image Resolution

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have some image I got from the web. Let's say that the max size I can make it without pix elating is 500 x 500. So with that said, should I make the @2x version of it, simply the 500 x 500 version, and regular version (ie for non retina) 250 x 250? Just a little confused about sizing the image correctly for the right screen resolution and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you said is correct.

Keep in mind though that once you put it on the device the @2x will display as 250x250 pts on a retina screen.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So the 2x will display as 250x250, but it'll still look good if I enlarge it up to 500 x 500? Also wondering, why wouldn't I just put the 1x and 2x version as both 500 x 500?

Comment: Because then it will display on screen as a 500x500 image. You won't be able to enlarge it on a retina screen as it is still 500 pixels wide and high, it just measures as 250 points.

Answer (score 0):

If the @2x version is 500 x 500 then it will be treated at load time as a 250 x 250 double-resolution image (`scale` = 2).